# PyQt5.How to fill the table widget based on several arguments?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qdialog

I am working on a customers record programm,that will be used in beauty saloon.

[image: Main interface].

So, I need to fill my table widget using this dialog window.

[image]

And each record need to be placed in exact time position. So,how can it be achieved?

Here is my Interface and Dialog code created by QtDesigner.
Table Widget

```
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 521, 781))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(25)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    #and so on...
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Главная"))
    self.addclient.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Записать клиента"))
    self.uslugi.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список услуг"))
    self.mastera.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список мастеров"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Время"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мастер"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Услуга"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя "))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Номер"))
    __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
    #...
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

And Dialog window

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(281, 176)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 71, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(Dialog)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 194, 22))
        self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 91, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 121, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 111, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Новый клиент"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Услуга"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Мастер"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Дата и время:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Контактный номер:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Имя клиента"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Добавить клиента"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Отмена записи"))
```

So i need inftomation in Dialog's input fields to be placed in exact time in a table widget. I'll appreciate any help! Sorry for QtDesigner abuse :D

This is a Record client button function that opens the dialog  window

```
class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.addclient.clicked.connect(self.addclientfunction)

def addclientfunction(self):
    self.dialog = MyDialog()
    self.dialog.show()
```

Entire MyWidnow Class

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(860, 803)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 331, 191))
    self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
    self.addclient = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.addclient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 350, 331, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Verdana")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.addclient.setFont(font)
    self.addclient.setObjectName("addclient")
    self.uslugi = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.uslugi.setEnabled(True)
    self.uslugi.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 270, 331, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Verdana")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.uslugi.setFont(font)
    self.uslugi.setObjectName("uslugi")
    self.mastera = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.mastera.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 190, 331, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Verdana")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.mastera.setFont(font)
    self.mastera.setObjectName("mastera")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 521, 781))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(25)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(10, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(11, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(12, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(13, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(14, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(15, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(16, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(17, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(18, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(19, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(20, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(21, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(22, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(23, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(24, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
    item.setFont(font)
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(5, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(6, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(7, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(8, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(9, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(10, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(11, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(12, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(13, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(14, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(15, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(16, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(17, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(18, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(19, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(20, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(21, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(22, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(23, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(24, 0, item)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Главная"))
    self.addclient.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Записать клиента"))
    self.uslugi.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список услуг"))
    self.mastera.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список мастеров"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Время"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мастер"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Услуга"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя "))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Номер"))
    __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(5, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(6, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(7, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(8, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "12:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(9, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "12:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(10, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "13:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(11, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "13:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(12, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "14:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(13, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "14:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(14, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "15:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(15, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "15:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(16, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "16:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(17, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "16:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(18, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "17:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(19, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "17:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(20, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "18:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(21, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "18:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(22, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "19:00"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(23, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "19:30"))
    item = self.tableWidget.item(24, 0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "20:00"))
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

Comment: With which button should the dialog window be opened?

Comment: ou could place the entire MainWindow_UI widget

Comment: Record client button,but I already coded it.

Comment: I want to execute your code but I find it hard to rebuild your code, please put it completely

Comment: added full MyWindow class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156464/discussion-between-akeg-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Does the part of the date have any special requirements? Should the data be placed in a specific row?

Comment: Actually,I want the time table widget to change pages,so each page is exact date. and if user set the date on tommorow,or some other day it actually place information on that page. but I don't know if it even possible with this widget

Comment: That is not possible with QTableWidget, you could give some solution but first we will end this problem. I understand that you want to put the data in the row where the time is. It's okay?

Comment: Also combo boxes are dont have anything in them yet,this is what two buttons under the calendar are for. I'm thinking about windows that contain lists of services and masters,so combo boxes can show information from them

Comment: Yes, sure ,it will be great

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the code of the design is not recommended if you are a beginner, so it is best to create new classes that implement the logic and use the design, these will be Dialog and MainWindow.

**Dialog:**
To handle some tasks easily we will connect the addClient and cancel buttons to the accept and reject slots so that we can use the dialog in a non-modal way and use exec_() that returns one code if it is accepted and another if it is canceled. a method must be created that collects input information.

**MainWindow:**
the clicked Record Client signal is connected to a slot where the dialog is displayed and the data of the dialog is collected. a logic is created to get the correct row and add the elements.

```
class Dialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # cancel
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        # accept
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm")

    def data(self):
        master = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        service = self.comboBox.currentText()
        name = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        contact_number = self.lineEdit.text()
        time = self.dateTimeEdit.time()
        return master, service, name, contact_number, time

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.addclient.clicked.connect(self.onAddClient)

    def onAddClient(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            master, service, name, contact_number, time = dialog.data()
            row = int(QTime(8, 0).secsTo(time)/(30*60))
            if row >= 0:
                for k, text in enumerate([master, service, name, contact_number]):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, k+1, QTableWidgetItem(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be prefix QtWidgets. before name QDialog,QMainWindow.
Works perfectly,Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to import. I Use: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QMainWindow` :P

Comment: If you want to manage the table as if they were pages I recommend using a QTableView, save the information in a database, use QSqlTableModel.

Comment: O,yeah,I Imported it in other way,that's why there was an error, your way is more convinient indeed :D

Comment: see this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html